# Are there any best practices for ERC-721 token ids?

Tags: nft, erc-721

The [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification) specification indexes NFTs by a `tokenId`, a variable of type `uint256`.

Are there any best practices on how the ids should be generated?

For instance, is it fine to use a simple integer counter that starts at 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) it mentions the **NFT Identifiers**.

It states:

> While some ERC-721 smart contracts may find it convenient to start with ID 0 and simply increment by one for each new NFT, callers SHALL NOT assume that ID numbers have any specific pattern to them, and MUST treat the ID as a “black box”.

So anyway you choose as long as the identifier is unique is good by standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use integer counters to increment the `tokenId` and because in Ethereum, transactions are processed sequentially (based on transaction gas fees chosen by the validators), the counters will work correctly.